# JSP form submit - Can I reference a specific method in my java class?

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml

I'm restricted to work on an enterprise software project using Netbeans IDE, and no frameworks.

The front-end display is `register.jsp`.  My Model package contains `Customer.java` class, with some getters and setters.  A Data package contains 'CustomerData.java', with DB functions related to the Customer: registration, log-in, etc.  `CustomerData` extends `HttpServlet`.

I need to reference a specific method from the `CustomerData` class from my registration form. Is this possible to do?

If this is possible to do, what should the `web.xml` file entry be for the `servlet` and `servletmapping`?

Here is code.

**Register.jsp**

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="CustomerData/RegisterCustomer">
......
</form>
```

**CustomerData.java** skeleton:

```
public class CustomerData extends HttpServlet {

    public void registerCustomer(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // this is the method I need to reference. It creates a db connection, checks to see if
        // the Customer is already in the DB, and if not, registers the user.
    }

    public void loginCustomer(HTTPServlet request)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // Some other Customer data method that will need to be called from my login.jsp page
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
       // some helper methods or validation methods for Customer
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot make out anything from the information given. Please be specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry Ck I didn't provide more info. I just basically needed to see how I can call one of those methods in CustomerData.java from Register.jsp. Bhavik provided the answer I was looking for. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you the below thing.

In the JSP page you can define one parameter say `opr` where you can set value of the operation.

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="CustomerData/">
<input type=hidden name=opr id=opr value=1
......
</form>
```

In the Servlet you can handle the operation by the operation value passed as below

```
public doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
        int operation = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("opr"));

        if (operation == 1){
            registerCustomer(req);
        }else if (operation == 2){
            loginCustomer(req);
        }else if (operation == 3){
            SomeOtherMethod();
        }...
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be done by using [getPathInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29)

Assuming your servlet mapping is

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CustomerData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CustomerData/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Calling

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
```

will give you the value `'/RegisterCustomer'` in pathInfo.  From there it should be rather trivial to figure out what method needs to be called.  Don't forget to ad check code to deal with all kinds of abuse that might be thrown at the servlet (eg no "method name" is given, nonexisting method names are specified, etc).

Comment: This is also a great solution! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.